# dense set examples

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Which of the following sets are dense in $\mathbb R$ with respect to the usual topology.

1. $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2: x \in \mathbb N\}$
2. $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:x+y$ is a rational number$\}$
3. $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2: x +y^2= 5\}$

4.$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2: xy\neq 0\}$

It can have multiple option right.

1 is clearly not true.
again in 2. $ x+y$  rational implies $x $and $y$ both are rational so it is dense.
what about the other options, no idea.

Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: when $x+y$ is ratinal, it does not imply $x,y$ rational, think $\sqrt2,-\sqrt2$.

Comment: yeah....thanks.

Comment: And clearly, the last one is dense since you only remove the $x=0$ and $y=0$ line from $R^2$ and it is easy to show that they lie in closure of the set.

Answer (score 1):

For (2), what does $\{(x,y):x+y\in\Bbb Q\}$ look like for each individual fixed $y\in\Bbb R$? Now what does the union of these sets look like in the plane? Do you think it's dense or no? Can you prove it?

For (3) & (4), draw the corresponding graphs (or for (4), the graph of its complement, $xy=0$) to get an idea for whether you believe each is dense or no, then you should be able to prove it.

Comment: (2) is much simpler if you just note that $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is a subset of the set in question.

Comment: That is a good point.

Comment: For 3) it is a parabola , only the outline here so its closure can't be $\mathbb R^2$...then can we conclude that 2) and 4) are true? 2) have some irrationals so it is an itermediary set of$ \mathbb Q^2$ and $\mathbb R^2$, then its closure is $\mathbb R^2$. Am I right?